# How can I use `pkg-config` with clangd?

Tags: gtk, pkg-config, clangd

I have started writing a GTK App in C, and since I am using `clangd` as my language server, I want to configure it. The problem is, `clangd` won't listen when I pass this as my compiler flags:

```
CompileFlags:
        Add: [ $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) ],
        Remove: [ ],
        Compiler: clang
```

I need to fix this if I want to make any use of the language server, so what do I do?
(I use VSCode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.clangd` config file does not support executing commands via `$(command)`.

The recommended way to configure a project for use with clangd is to generate a `compile_commands.json` file based on your project's build metadata.

A simple way to do this is using [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear). For example, if your project is built using `make`, you can run `bear -- make` and `bear` will generate a `compile_commands.json` file based on the compiler commands that `make` invoked.

For more sophisticated build systems, the build system may itself provide a way to generate a `compile_commands.json` file (for example, CMake has `DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON`).

For more details, see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup.

Comment: The correct command is `bear -- make` if `make` is used.

Comment: @chenzhongpu Thank you, updated. (A previous version of `bear` used `bear make`.)